# Foreach to Variable in Php

Tags: php, foreach

I have some code that scrapes information from a website, this works fine and outputs the information from the website on to the screen perfectly.

But i am having trouble outputing he information in to a variable, below is the foreach of the code.

```
  foreach($html->find('<p itemprop="description">') as $e)
  echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

I have tried to output $html, but this gives me all of the page and i just want to capture the innertext section.  I have tried to also output $e but this doesn't give me anything.

is there away to display innertext as a variable?

Comment: *"Is there away to display innertext as a variable?"* - Sure, `echo $var = $e->innertext . '<br>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the values to a variable.

```
$text = "";
foreach($html->find('<p itemprop="description">') as $e) {
    $text .= $e->innertext . '<br>';
}
echo $text;
```